# HTML navigation menu that doesn't reset content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I'm building a webapp with jQuery and Bootstrap 3. 
On my main page (see code below), I want to have a navigation menu with 2 items, each of them pointing to distinct content.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script src="./js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="././Bootstrap-3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="./Bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div id = "menu">
             <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                <li class = "active"><a>Panel A</a></li>
                <li><a>Panel B</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like my 2 contents (A & B) to be stored in separate HTML files, and I need the user to be able to switch seamlessly forth and back between panels A and B without loosing the state of each panel (i.e I'm on panel A, then I go to panel B and back to panel A: panel A should be in the exact same state as when I left it).
I also need these panel files to load dynamically at first access.

I have tried to have my menu items load the panel content via an  but this doesn't work as it resets the state of this panel.

Should I go for iframes or hidden divs instead, and how would this look line code-wise?

Comment: on page load, load the tab contents via ajax and append it to dom. Then simply show hide them.

Comment: use bootstrap tabs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: You could use bootstrap tabs, or maybe you could use sections and play with hide/show

Comment: I've tried to use bootstrap tabs, and indeed this solves part of my problem. What I realise then is that I may have conflicts / duplicates in Javascript variables / functions between my different page html sub-files (as everything is loaded into the same "body"). Is it then possible to use some kind of "namespace" in my Javascript code, or should I just make sure that every JS variable / function has a unique name across all page files ? Or use iframes ?